# Possible to put defined variable in array call

Tags: javascript

I have a quick question. here is my code:

```
d3.csv("test1.csv", function(data) {



            var year = "state";


        .domain([
                d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }), 
                d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })
            ]);
```

I am querying a csv file here. d3.min and max are returning the coloumn named "value" using "return d.value;".

Is it possible to have my year variable defined above this code in this call instead of hard coding the word "value" from the column name?

I would like to use the variable instead as then I could change it with one change.

I have tried return d.year but this obviously looks for a column called year and not my variable called year.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the bracket syntax:

```
var year = "state";
// ...
.domain([
  d3.min(data, function(d) { return d[ year ]; }), 
  d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[ year ]; })
]);
```

`d.year` refers to the property `year`, as it is just an identifier.

If you want to refer the variable `year` and thus use its content as the identifier, you have to use the bracket syntax.

Comment: thank you, a bit rusty on the javascript. Your help has been great.